# User Defined Exception Class: unreported exception InvalidUserInputException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, validation, exception

I'm learning how to make my own exceptions in Java right now and was looking at this tutorialspoint page as a reference (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) and trying to adapt what they did as best I could to what I want to do. Primarily, I have a program that takes input from my user. In order to make sure my user only inputs valid choices, I need to throw an exception when they try to order an invalid type of vehicle.

When I try to compile my program I get the following error:

`Orders.java:25: error: unreported exception InvalidUserInputException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                orderNewVehicle(Orders);
                               ^`

inside main method:

```
try{
    orderNewVehicle(Orders);
} catch (InvalidUserInputException e){
    System.out.println("You've requested an invalid vehicle type. Please only enter " + e.getValidVehicles());
    orderNewVehicle(Orders);
}
```

orderNewVehicle method that's supposed to throw my exception:

```
public static void orderNewVehicle(ArrayList listOfOrders) throws InvalidUserInputException{

    String vehicleType = "";
    System.out.print("Do you want to order a Truck (T/t), Car (C/c), Bus(M/m), Zamboni(Z/z), or Boat(B/b)? ");
    Boolean validVehicle = false;   
    while(validVehicle.equals(false)) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String potentialInput = scan.next();
        if(!(potentialInput.equals("c") || potentialInput.equals("C") || potentialInput.equals("t") || potentialInput.equals("T") || potentialInput.equals("b") || potentialInput.equals("B") || potentialInput.equals("m") || potentialInput.equals("M") || potentialInput.equals("z") || potentialInput.equals("Z"))) {
            // System.out.print("Invalid input. Only enter c/C for Car, t/T for Truck, m/M for Bus, z/Z for Zamboni, or b/B for Boat. Please Try Again: ");
            scan.nextLine(); //Clear carriage return if one present
            throw new InvalidUserInputException();
        } else {
            validVehicle = true;
            vehicleType = potentialInput;
            scan.nextLine();   
        }            
    }
    System.out.println("");
    // stuff that happens once we get past the input check

}
```

my exception class:

```
public class InvalidUserInputException extends Exception {
    private String vehicleTypes = "c/C for Car, t/T for Truck, m/M for Bus, z/Z for Zamboni, or b/B for Boat";

    public InvalidUserInputException() {

    }

    public String getValidVehicles() {
        return vehicleTypes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current logic is that in the `catch` block you are again calling a method which might throw an exception.  The compiler is just telling you that you have to catch that other exception as well.

As an immediate fix to your problem, you may try something along these lines:

```
final String msg = "You've requested an invalid vehicle type. Please only enter ";
boolean success = false;
do {
    try {
        orderNewVehicle(Orders);
        success = true;
    }
    catch (InvalidUserInputException e){
        System.out.println(msg + e.getValidVehicles());
    }
} while (!success);
```

In the above version, we loop, calling `orderNewVehicle`, until a successful call is made.  We know that a call has been successful if the `success` flag can be set to true, which would mean that an `InvalidUserInputException` has *not* be thrown.

Comment: Ohhhh. I hadn't thought to do it that way. Well, I probably would've thought to do it that way if I'd realized that I wasn't supposed to call the function again inside that try catch. Now that I look at it again I might have been getting into some recursive type shenanigans. This makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!